# How can I replace this sticky fan foam?

Tags: fan, cooling

I had to disassemble a CPU cooling system in a notebook.

The fans were sticked onto the chassic a bit with this sticking foam style tape:

[image]

However it is not sticking anymore after removal.

What is the name of this?

Especially as it forms a "U" shape, so it's clearly something special.

Comment: Was that foam sticky on both sides?

Comment: No, only the bottom side. Major part is still sticked onto the fan, but as I have access to it I'd like to know if I can replace it for prolonging the lifetime.

Comment: Then I would suggest you use a little dab of pattex or other contact adhesive. Pattex should work up to 110°C and stays elastic. Note that contact adhesives have special applying procedure: clean both surfaces, apply on both surfaces, wait until dry enough to touch (10-30min) (don't touch the gluing surface, keep a little dab on some paper nearby), press surfaces together with much force, wait 12-24h

Comment: "clean both surfaces": there is only one surface in here, no? :)

Comment: One surface might be a tape, but it could be a good idea to clean that as well with some IPA if there is an excessive amount of dust on there. Worst that can happen is the glue on the tape dissolving, but will get fixed shortly after.

Comment: 3M double stick tape will do very well, remove the old tape first.